# Shouldn't all processes get blocked when the CPU is switched to kernel mode?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, kernel, cpu

When a process makes a system call, the CPU will be switched to kernel mode, and the process will be blocked (because if the process is not blocked, then it can execute privileged instructions when the CPU becomes in kernel mode).

But shouldn't all processes also get blocked? because what if when the CPU is switched to kernel mode, some other process execute a privileged instruction (for example: `hlt`)?

Comment: `some other process execute a privileged instruction` - Do you mean a process executed on **other CPU core**?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Why are you asking this, will the processes on the other cores not get blocked, while the processes on the same core get blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel or user mode is a **per-CPU** attribute, that is at the same moment one CPU may be in *kernel mode* while another CPU - in *user mode*.

As you can see, nothing prevents another CPU from executing a process: privileged instructions are still prohibited on it.

Comment: I didn't understand your second paragraph.

Comment: It means that other processes may safely be executed on other CPUs. This is answer on your question `But shouldn't all processes also get blocked?`.

Comment: When you say "per-CPU", does that also apply to per-core? so one core can be in kernel mode while another core in user mode?

Comment: Yes, per-CPU means "per-core". In *programming* (but not in *hardware*), CPU usually denotes single core.

Comment: So if a process is running on **core 1** made a system call, will all the processes on that core be blocked until the kernel finishes executing the system call?

Comment: What do you mean by `all the processes on that core be blocked`? If scheduler decides that the core should execute other process, the core will switch to that process, and mode will be changed to "user".

Comment: So let's say that while the kernel is executing the system call, the scheduler decided to go to another process, now like you said the mode will be changed to "user", and then the scheduler decided to go back to the process that made the system call, now the mode will be changed to "kernel" until the kernel finishes executing the system call, correct? (assume that both processes are running on the same core)